# Is the wordplay between Riker and Guinan original?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, riker

In Season 2 Episode 10, Riker and Guinan try to show Wesley how to interact with a girl and have the following exchange:

> Riker: "Now, the first words out of your mouth are the most important.
>   You may want to start with something like this here." [To Guinan] "You
>   are the most beautiful woman in the galaxy." [To Wesley] "But that
>   might not work."
>
> Guinan: "Yes! Yes, it would."
>
> Riker: "You don't know how long I've wanted to tell you that."
>
> Guinan: "But you were afraid."
>
> Riker: "Yes."
>
> Guinan: "Of me?"
>
> Riker: "Of us. Of what we might become."
>
> Riker: "Or that you might think it was a li(n)e."
>
> Guinan: "Maybe I do think it's a li(n)e."
>
> Riker: "Then you think I'm not sincere."
>
> Guinan: "I din't say that. There's nothing wrong with a li(n)e. It's like
>   knocking at the door."
>
> Riker: "Then you're inviting me in?"
>
> Guinan: "I'm not sending you away."
>
> Riker: "That's more than I expected."
>
> Guinan: "Is it as much as you hoped?"
>
> Riker: "To hope is to recognize the possibility. I had only dreams."
>
> Guinan: "Dreams can be dangerous."
>
> Riker: "Not these dreams. I dream of a galaxy where your eyes are the
>   stars, and the universe worships the night."
>
> Guinan: "Careful! Putting me on a pedestal so high, you might not be
>   able to reach me."
>
> Riker: "Then I'll learn how to fly. You are the heart of my day, and
>   the soul of my night."

-- ["The Dauphin", Stardate 42568.8](http://stng.36el.com/st-tng/episodes/quotes/136.html)

I was watching this episode the other day with my Kids and I heard this exchange and it rang a bell, my thoughts were that it may be an adaptation from Romeo and Juliet, I did some searching and can't find anything with the basic keywords on Google.

is this truly an original dialogue? if not, where is it from?

Comment: Terrible, terrible dating advice from the 24th century....

Comment: And people would wonder why Riker was single...

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish i don't know, Worf had some real good advice there *"No, no, no. Men do not roar. Women roar. Then they hurl heavy objects. And claw at you."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It appears to be original to Star Trek

Started with a basic Google search on [one of the distinctive quotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To%20hope%20is%20to%20recognize%20the%20possibility.%20I%20had%20only%20dreams.%22), followed by one [specifically negating "Star Trek"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To%20hope%20is%20to%20recognize%20the%20possibility.%20I%20had%20only%20dreams.%22%20-star%20-trek). Both times only returned references to the instance in Star Trek. The same applies for [other quotes I searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20dream%20of%20a%20galaxy%20where%20your%20eyes%20are%20stars%22%20-star%20-trek).

Next I checked the [Memory Alpha article on The Dauphin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dauphin), and that too provided no reference to another source.

If it were from another well know work, I'd have expected more to come up, or at least attribution given. Since there was not, I think it's safe to say that it's original writing.

Comment: I was really hoping for something more than this, I will give it a few days before I consider accepting this as an answer. Very good answer, and thorough too.  thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Malachi Definitely understood. If someone finds the evidence you're hoping for then that absolutely deserves acceptance. But I tried beyond what I listed above and found nothing, and am content with my efforts.

Comment: I also looked with "-riker -guinan"  I found the lines I was looking for in poetry and such, but it was after the script was written.  I am thinking that maybe some Fan asked about it during an interview or something, that is more what I am hoping pops up